# Hadoop Ecosystem and its workflow

Tags: hadoop

Which one should start first..in sequential order .. when we have Oozie,HDFS,Hive Zookeeper and other tools in the Hadoop ecosystem?
It an administrative question posed by my superiors .

Comment: why not start by searching on google?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possibilities based on the deployment scenarios like for example if you have highly available Hadoop (NameNode high-availability, ResourceManager/JobTracker high-availability) or have HBase in the cluster then the order would be something like this:

1. Zookeeper
2. HDFS
3. HBase (if used)
4. Yarn/MapReduce
5. Other Ecosystem tools (hive, pig, sqoop, oozie)

It doens't matter the start order of the eco-system tools.

Comment: This is a pretty good basic ordering.